# Quasar CLI integrated with Laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have an application in which I am developing using Laravel + VueJs with Laravel mix (both back and front end within the same folder structure) and now I want to start using Quasar.

Is it possible to integrate the Quasar CLI together with the Laravel Mix and continue using the same folder structure? If so, how to generate the build script?

Will there be any changes in the deploy script?

Comment: Use Quasar UMD version.

Comment: I've been doing something along these lines - adapted from this article:
https://medium.com/@lalrinfela/laravel-with-quasar-spa-7b298024f106

It's not efficient though - I have to run the quasar build command and then the npm run dev command (or npm run prod on production).. quasar files compile then the npm dev command compiles the css, copies things over to the public directory.. but those two steps (especially the quasar build command) are slow and cumbersome - so I'd love it if there was a better way.

Comment: @DylanGlockler how do you run this? It returns an error with Quasar dev command,

Comment: @jm-macatangay did you figure it out? I was out of touch a while and just saw this. Been working on a series of steps to get Laravel and Quasar to play nice and I'm mostly there - just have an issue where I have to change the name of the public directory when I run my build. Can post the steps if helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211320/hot-reload-issue-when-using-quasar-with-laravel-and-sanctum

Answer (score 2):

I assume that Quasar CLI builds all assets into static files; js / css. My opinion is compiling Mix's assets first and pass the out put (js / css) to Quasar by configuring at `quasar.config.js` then running `quasar build`.

Or It might able to config `quasar.config.js` to load all Mix' assets.

this docs might help https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-quasar.conf.js.html